# Declaring C++ array with or without the "new" keyword

Tags: c++, arrays

In C++, what's the difference between this:

```
char example[10];
```

and this:

```
char* example = new char[10];
```

in both cases, I'm not initializing the content of the arrays, but just wanting to get 10-bytes in memory allocated to the character array. In both cases, I intend to then use sprintf() to assign a string value to them with no intermediate step.

Comment: In C, `new char[10]` is a syntax error.

Comment: @KamilCuk ah, well, I guess I only meant to direct this question to C++ then, since that's what I'm coding in for an Arduino project

Comment: @user751612 I would expect array to be the most used data structure in C++ (when counting `std::vector`).

Comment: @eerorika sorry, I've been programming in C++/Qt libraries for 10 years. Haven't seen the standard library used in 10 years. I'm rusty.

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> char example[10];
> ```

`example` is an array of 10 chars. Depending on context, it has automatic or static storage. The size can only be compile time constant. The array is destroyed and deallocated automatically.

> ```
> char* example = new char[10];
> ```

`example` is a pointer. It is not an array. It points to first element of an array in dynamic storage. The size of dynamic array can be determined at runtime. The array is not destroyed and deallocated automatically. If not deallocated, the memory will leak.

Dynamic allocation is generally slower than static or automatic. On the other hand, the amount of memory available for automatic storage is typically very limited.

Bare owning pointers should be avoided. Best practice is to use a smart pointer or a RAII container such as `std::vector` when dynamic array is needed.

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
char example[10];
```

Declares `example` as an array of `char` containing 10 elements.  If declared at file scope, this array will typically reside in the data segment, while if it is declared at block scope it will typically reside on the stack.

In contrast, this:

```
char* example = new char[10];
```

Declares `example` as a pointer to `char`, and initializes it with a pointer to dynamically allocated memory which points to the first member of a 10 member array of `char`.  This dynamically allocated memory typically resides on the heap.

Note also that `new` is specific to C++.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, it sounds like both would work if my goal is just to pass the array to sprintf() to fill the contents of it?

I'm doing something like this:

`sprintf(example, "%s", "Test");`
`sprintf(otherArray, "%s", example");`

Comment: @user751612 `new[]` requires a call to `delete[]`, so as to not leak memory.  The `sprintf` call does not know if the buffer, regardless of what you use, is big enough to hold the information.  Idiomatic C++ would use `std::ostringstream` to format the output, or some other library that doesn't have these potential issues.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that, in your first example you are have to already know at declare this char array his size, but in your second example, you are declare char array with pointer, which points on some value. That means you can only declare some char pointer without knowing the size of the char array. It is very usefull for programs, where the user has to write his nickname as input, maximal lenght of nickname can be 10 characters, but it can be less then 10 characters, that means you have to use pointers for dynamic allocating memory so as not to use too much unused memory.

For example:

```html
int main()
{
  char nm[10]; //Create char array, where you will save an input
  char* nickname; //Declare pointer
  std::cout << "Nickname: " << std::endl;
  fflush(stdin);
  gets(nm); //Save input

  // Here we go find the size of used memory in char array nm
  int size_of_nm = 0;
  for (char i : nnnn) 
  {
      if (i == '\0') //If char i is equal to zero character, we find the size of used                                                   
      {              //memory in char array nm
          break;
      }

      else //If i is not equal to zero character, we do not find the size of used                                                                 
      {    //memory in char array nm and loop will continue

          size_of_nm++; //Size counter plus one
      }
  }

  nickname = new char[size_of_nm + 1]; //Create new pointer on char array and set the 
                                       //size of used memory in char array                                                               
                                      //plus one, because the char array is always 
                                     //ending with zero character
}
```

But I recommend using a strings. It is more safer, because you dont have to know the size of used memory, memory of string is allocated automatically.